# finding the distance from point A to point B for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, uiaccelerometer

Hey I'm trying to calculate the distance of 1 spot to another on the iPhone (horizontally) Im not sure how

Comment: open CGPointExtension.h in the cocos2d project, you'll find ccpDistance and others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to create to instance of CLLocation, and call the methods to calculate.

```
CLLocation *locationOne = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[point coordinate].latitude longitude:[point coordinate].longitude];
CLLocation *locationTwo = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[secondPoint coordinate].latitude longitude:[secondPoint coordinate].longitude];
double distanceInMeters = [locationOne distanceFromLocation:locationTwo];
```

If you want distances between two points, you should remember Pitagora:

```
CGPoint pointA, pointB;
double distancesInPoints = sqrt((pointA.x-pointB.x)*(pointA.x-pointB.x) + (pointA.y-pointB.y)*(pointA.y-pointB.y));
```

Comment: Of course you need Core Location framework to you project, and ViewController.

Comment: you assume geographic locations were asked for, more likely it's just CGPoint distances